# rsnapshot: why daily/weekly/monthly instead of many daily backups?

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

The daily/weekly/monthly backup scheme is often recommended for backups. As far as I understand rsnapshot, backups are really cheap due to hardlinking.

Is there any advantage of say

```
retain      daily   7
retain      weekly  4
retain      monthly 12
```

compared to

```
retain      daily   365
```

if every new backup just takes a little disk space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're cheap, but they're not free.  You can keep a year's worth of dailies if you want, and if you've got the space, but the moment you start to have disk space pressure, the cost/benefit of keeping them all isn't going to be worth it.  Once you're more than a week out, the need for such high fidelity backups tends to disappear.